# how to create timezone object in gwt?

Tags: gwt

```
TimeZone tzTarget = TimeZone.createTimeZone( "Asia/Dhaka" );
```

While creating timezone object in GWT i am getting error:

> Exception while loading module com.test.client.GWT_project. See
>   Development Mode for details.
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:406) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError:
>   JSON.parse: unexpected character Asia/Dhaka at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.JsonUtils.throwIllegalArgumentException(JsonUtils.java:118)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>   at com.google.gwt.core.client.JsonUtils.safeEval(JsonUtils.java) at
>   com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZoneInfo$.buildTimeZoneData(TimeZoneInfo.java:42)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone.createTimeZone(TimeZone.java:75)
>   at com.test.client.GWT_project.onModuleLoad(GWT_project.java:54) ... 9
>   more

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
private static final TimeZoneConstants t = (TimeZoneConstants) GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class);

TimeZone tzTarget = TimeZone.createTimeZone( t.asiaDhaka());
```

Comment: I think this is mistaken - you need to pass the JSON itself in, via the properties listed there. Something like `TimeZoneConstants constants = GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class);`, then `TimeZone.createTimeZone(constants.asiaDhaka());`

Comment: You are right - I focused on a slash in "Asia/Dhaka" :)

Comment: @DadaKambale: Then you can accept and maybe upvote the answer. This is how we show appreciation at StackOverflow. Welcome to the community!